# How to run/debug Web Application project without cache/cookies?

Tags: javascript, css, html, caching, cookies

i am developing a web application using HTML5, javascript, css and my server side language is Java with Spring MVC framework. But when i try to run/debug my application somehow, when i change the css or javascript or something else in my VIEW side, my application SOMETIMES (Not everytime but mostly i encountered this problem, it give me some head ache like WHY i still got these error, i already changed them and suddenly just like remember, 'Ohh! i need to clear my web browser cache'), it kind of not refreshing with my new code, sometimes they stuck, but i already change the code, still it doesn't show what i am changing (especially Javascript and CSS).

What i do is, i did clean all my cookies, browser history, cache or anything that showed up in my mozilla and chrome browser, which is i use for developing my application.

How to run/debug my web application in a CLEAN or NEW state, so i don't have to clear history, cache or the others option to have a refreshed code?

Comment: I use incognito mode in chrome to develop.

Comment: You can add directives in your web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both browsers have settings to disable the browser cache whilst the dev tools are open.

[Chrome settings](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings)

[Firefox settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox)

Answer on the chrome tools here: [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)